# SQL Server Explicit Transactions Behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have just had to do a SQL exam and I really struggled with 2 questions around transactions, it has been submitted, so this is just for my sanity... What are the answers to these?

Sorry if this shouldn't be here, or if these should be 2 separate questions.

1.

```
Employee X has a salary of 40,000
a. User A begins a transaction and updates employee X's salary to salary * 1.1
b. User B begins a transaction and updates employee X's salary to salary * 1.25
c. User A rolls back their transaction
d. User B commits their transaction
```

What is Employee X's salary?
(I went with 50,000, there was no mention of transaction isolation level)

2.
A script is built up as follows -

```
a. Transaction start
b. Insert record into table 1
c. Create savepoint
d. Insert record into table 2
e. Rollback to the save point created after the insert into table 1
f. Insert a record into table 3
g. Commit the transaction
```

Which tables were records inserted into?
(I went with table 1 only)

Comment: Feels like the isolation level should be rather important for #1, for example `READ UNCOMMITTED` vs. `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking while I was trying to answer the question, couldnt understand how I could tell without knowing.

Comment: If using the default `READ COMMITTED` level, your answer would afaict be correct.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - For the statement `UPDATE Employee SET salary = salary * @I WHERE EmployeeId = 'X'` it doesn't depend on the isolation level at all. `B` will be blocked at all isolation levels by A's update until A rollsback. The end result will be 50,000.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hm, then I must be misunderstanding what `READ UNCOMMITTED` does (which is quite possible), why would B be blocked in that isolation level when it should be equivalent to (or even less restrictive than) `NOLOCK`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - The isolation level only makes any difference when reading data. An `UPDATE` query will always take locks. If the transaction consisted of two different statements (a `SELECT` that read the value followed by an `UPDATE` that used the value) then it would be possible for a lost update to occur.

Comment: @MartinSmith Did some further reading, and although I can't find docs that are extremely clear on the subject, I believe you're 100% correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question 1 assuming we have default transaction isolation level i.e Read Committed . your answer is right.

**Question 1**

> 1. User one Begin a transaction and does not commit it
> 2. User two tries to update the same record but his Update will be blocked until user one rolls back
>       his transaction, But once he rolls back his transaction it will be updated to `Salary * 1.25` which is 50000.

**Question 2**

> 1. Record inserted in table one with a savepoint means if this transaction is rolled back it
>         will not be rolled back all but to the last saved point.
> 2. Insert into table 2 and then rolled back , which will rollback the insert into table 2 but
>         not the insert in table 1 which is protected by the savepoint.
> 3. Insert into table 3 and commmit. Which will save inserts made into table 1 and 3 to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didn't get your 1st question.

For Question 2 , Data will be inserted in table1 and table3.